# WCF normal time response or not?

Tags: c#, wcf

I noticed that methods which I use in my self hosted wcf-appliactions are slow.
I write test method

```
    public int MeasureTime()
    {
        int begin = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) Console.WriteLine(i);
        int end = Environment.TickCount;
        return end-begin;
    }
```

This method return value about 300 ms. If I measure it in my localhost client app which I have time about 600 ms. It is normal that I have such big delays?

I use basicHttpBinding.

Comment: Besides the actual running time of the function itself, the invocation via WCF involves serialization and deserialization, sending documents via http and the like; in my opinion, the delay is not surprising.

Comment: What values does it return in repeated calls? There is some overhead in WCF activation, but even for HTTP it shouldn't be this high. Is the difference (between running the code locally and via HTTP WCF) similar if you don't write to console from the code? Try to remove code to localize the bottleneck, or use a profiling tool (such as the Visual Studio profiler) to find the hot spot.

Answer (score 0):

What does this have to do with WCF? I don't see any WCF code here.

You are measuring the time it takes to write a huge ton of text to the console. You aren't measuring WCF time.

I don't understand what you are aiming at. If you want to measure WCF round-trip time don't make the method do other stuff for 1e6 iterations.

A WCF call takes as long as the CPU need to process it plus a network round-trip. Like ~1ms.